# reverse lookup filter by value of an array in php union minus intersection

Tags: php

I was wondering if I have these two arrays

```
$arr = ["foo" => 1, "bar" => 2];
$arr_2 = array(1000, 1);
```

how can I setup a filter that lets through all the values that exist in `$arr_2` but do not exist in `$arr_1` in an efficient way for this result? In other words, is there a native way to get the union minus intersection of two arrays?

```
$answer = array(1000);
```

Thanks!

Comment: array_intersect/array_diff

Comment: You say union minus intersection (that'd be `(1000, 2)`), but then you counter that with an example that only shows `(1000)` as the desired result. The first one would require two operations, while the other one is simply [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff).

Comment: @El_Vanja is correct in saying that the expected answer is wrong -- there should be two items, either `[1000, 2]`, or `[1000, "bar" => 2]`, depending on your understanding of "union" and "intersection", @reactor

Comment: And also note that an actual union of these two arrays (`$arr + $arr_2`) would produce an array of 4 elements (not 3), since it considers keys as well.

Comment: Scratch that last couple of words, it considers keys, not values. I should probably sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you show as `$arr` is actually `$arr_1` then filter out those values from `$arr_2`:

```
$answer = array_diff($arr_2, $arr_1);
```

Or more complex:

```
$answer = array_filter($arr_2, function($v) use($arr_1) { return !in_array($v, $arr_1); });
```